In a topology where three different 3D spaces meet at a plane, what determines which way a moving object will go?
Mathematically, a flat 2D manifold in the X,Y plane that is folded down in the perpendicular direction to go into the X,Z plane has no intrinsic curvature. All of the rules of Euclidean geometry apply on a folded sheet of paper. So a Flatlander could not detect the fold. It would appear to him as a normal flat 2D plane. Same for us if our 3D space was folded down in a perpendicular direction in a 4 dimensional sense.
Suppose 3D space was folded down in two different perpendicular directions, both perpendicular to all three of our space dimensions. There are three 3D manifolds all meeting at the X,Y plane. If we picture it embedded in 5D hyperspace, the 3D space containing the X,Y,Z axes and the space containing X,Y,W axes and the space containing X,Y,V axes all meet at the common X,Y plane. If this were our real universe, an object following Newton's laws of motion in X,Y,Z space goes in a straight trajectory thru this X,Y plane. It wouldn't see the fold of space or detect anything unusual. It could end up in the X,Y,W space or the X,Y,V space. What determines which 3D space it enters?
This is analogous to a point mass confined to a 1D line that is the edge of a cube. When it comes to a corner, it has two possible paths. What determines which path it follows? An electron in a circuit randomly picks a path with a probability based on the resistance of that path. But an electron is a quantum object.
There is no gravity or any other forces on the object. Does it randomly go into one or the other 3D space, similar to the electron in a circuit? How could it be random? Newtonian mechanics is deterministic. This is not a quantum object. It is a large rock, not an atom. Would each molecule independently "choose" a 3D space, breaking the object apart. Or would binding forces hold the object together?
Perhaps such a topology is impossible in the real universe? If so, what law of physics does it violate? It is consistent with general relativity, isn't it? Is there some unknown law of physics that determines which 3D space the object enters? Is there some unknown law that prevents this topology from occurring?

You might want to use a set of laws more general than Newton’s, which hold in Euclidean geometry only.

Please clarify what you mean by "folded down in two different perpendicular directions". What sets of points are you identifying? You seem to be talking about 3 copies of the closed 3D half-space glued together.

I also suggest first considering the analogous situation of a point mass restricted to be on the edges of an ordinary 3D cube. Each corner is the endpoint where 3 edges meet at right angles. What happens when it reaches a corner?

"Mathematically, a flat 2D surface folded down over the edge of a desk has no curvature," Why wouldn't the curvature be infinite at the fold?

@D.Halsey It is only to a two-dimensional being that the fold has no curvature; such a being has a distance metric that only follows paths in two dimensions.   So, the presumption is a non-Euclidean metric space that is not accessible to our observations.

What is a "desk" in this context?  What does "folded" mean?  Why would an object on a straight trajectory in the XY plane leave that plane?    Et cetera.

You don't need to consider higher dimensions as the issue can be seen simply by considering a one dimensional trajectory in a plane i.e. a geometry like this:

If we assume that we have a "linelander" who can only perceive one spatial dimension the question is what happens at the point $A$ where the trajectory bifurcates?
The answer is to consider the situation from the point of view of the "flatlander" physicist observing the time evolution. As physicists we expect that our equations are causal i.e. whether the trajectory goes along the $B$ branch or the $C$ branch will be predictable from properties of the motion that we can measure. The "linelander" may not be able to observe the factors that control what happens at $A$, but from the 2D perspective the behaviour cannot be random there. There must be some force acting at $A$ that determines the direction and that as observed by the "flatlander" the trajectory must be predictable.
A real life example of this is the fact that electric field lines cannot cross.
